# Javascript: How to encrypt a zip file with RSA

Tags: javascript, file, rsa, jszip

I'm using [Cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico) to handle RSA encryption for chat but I'm running into trouble trying to encrypt a zip file after construction. I see the constructed file in the console. The console shows an encrypted string of the file but returns blank after decryption in the console.

Note: my decryption method works properly with text and base64

```
$(document).on("change", "#chatImage", function() {
    var rid = $(this).closest(".chat").data("id");
    var files = this.files;
    var zip = new JSZip();

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
        var file = files[i];
        zip.file(file.name, file);

        console.log("added", file.name);
        // console.log(file);
    }

    var eImgArray = {};
    $.ajax({
        url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
        action: 'get_room_member_keys',
        rid : rid,
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(html) {
            var pubKeys = $.parseJSON(html);
            $.each( pubKeys, function( key, value ) {
                var imgEncrypt = cryptico.encrypt(file, value);
                var imgSrc = imgEncrypt.cipher;
                eImgArray[key] = imgSrc;
            });
            var strImgArray = JSON.stringify(eImgArray);
            $("#chatFormCont input[name=image_data]").val(strImgArray);
            var foo = $("#chatFormCont input[name=image_data]").val();
            // console.log(foo);                             
        },
    });

    zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"}).then(function(content) {

        function show_all_images(relpath, file) {
            if (file.dir) {
                return file.forEach(show_all_images);
            }
            var img = $("#chatImagePreview");
            file.async("blob").then(function(blob) {
                var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                img.attr("src", src);
            });
        }
        new JSZip.loadAsync(content).then(zip => zip.forEach(show_all_images));
    });
});
```

Comment: Going to need a "working" example.

Comment: @Ouroborus why in this instance?

Comment: It seems like you have two async actions going on, `$.ajax` and `zip.generateAsync`. It's not obvious how or if they interact.

Comment: @Ouroborus The first is to grab a set of public keys for each user for encryption of the file. The second async is me retrieving the image from the file and adding it to a preview. I don't have to do it that way but I was making sure I could retrieve it. I just need to figure out the correct way to RSA encrypt a file after zipped from a file upload.